# Pivot table borders fail when expanding table in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a pivot table using VBA. Here is my code.

```
 .PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Fineline").ShowDetail = False

 'Create Borders

Range("A2:K2").BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("K" & .Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
Range(.Range("B1"), .Range("B" & .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
Range(.Range("C1"), .Range("E" & .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
Range(.Range("F1"), .Range("H" & .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
Range(.Range("I1"), .Range("K" & .Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
```

My pivot table is in tabular form so I am able to open and close certain tabs hence the first line of code to not show the detail. As you can see, I want to create a border around column C to E, F to H, and I to J). When I run the code, the table looks how it is supposed to. However, when I open a tab in the pivot table, all of my columns now have a border around it. I cannot figure out why the borders are doing this?

Thanks,

G

Comment: *I cannot figure out why the borders are doing this?* - because that's just what Excel does: if your pivot table layout isn't final, you'll lose any fancypants borders if you tweak it. It does that when you use Excel manually; there's no reason for VBA code to do anything different. Finalize your layout, *then* set the borders. FWIW there's literally 20-some built-in formats with fancy borders and shadings, built-in, that *do* preserve with layout modifications. Why not use that instead of manually drawn borders?

Comment: When I make the pivot table manually and then put the borders in, it works. I am not sure why this is the case.

Comment: How do I finalize my layout?

Answer (score 1):

PivotTables have 'Styles' that you can copy and amend. So you don't need to do this with VBA, but rather duplicate a style that looks something like you want, and make any changes you want, and it will be reapplied automatically.

To do this, right-click over a style in the Styles gallery and select *Duplicate...*:

[image]

...and then give it a name, and then click on any of the areas that you want to format differently:

[image]

For instance, if you want a border around the entire PivotTable, select *Whole Table* and then click the Format button, and select *Border* from the tab at the top of the dialog and then apply the formatting you want:

[image]

Then click OK to close the dialogs. The PivotTable will still look the same at this stage, because while you have set up a new Style, you haven't yet applied it to this PivotTable. So go back to the Styles gallery, click on the down arrow, and select your new PivotTable stlye from the *Custom* area:

[image]

Comment: *This* is how you format a pivot table. Anything else leads to madness. +1\